# How to create grouped and stacked bar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I'm trying to plot grouped and stacked bars in python. However, I want to add more bars in each group, e.g., E and F in df. Also, how can I show the legend for each color?

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(

    A=[1, 2],

    B=[3, 4],

    C=[5, 6],

    D=[7, 8],

    E=[9, 10],

    F=[1, 2]))
 
 
ax = plt.gca()
 

ab_bar_list = [ax.bar([0, 1], df.B, align='edge', width= 0.2),

               ax.bar([0, 1], df.A, align='edge', width= 0.2)]

cd_bar_list = [ax.bar([0, 1], df.D, align='edge',width= -0.2),

               ax.bar([0, 1], df.C, align='edge',width= -0.2)]

plt.show()
```